# Writing and limiting scope of custom styles

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using angular templates to load dynamic html. That template has defined its own css for tags.

Now when I load that template those css for tags get applied to entire page which I don't want. I want to maintain the main page css and template page css separate.

Creating classes and not writing css like `a,div{` for the template files/ main page is not feasible as templates are already created and they are huge files with these common tags and main page needs to be consistent with other main pages.

Does anyone know how to restrict use of css?

Comment: Is this Angular 1 or 2? Angular 2 templates that include styles only get applied to the component they are declared within.

Comment: "writing css like `a,div{`" - Sounds like a terrible practice, and the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes I know that. But they have been created already and I am supposed to alter them and use them as is. Can't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to restrict the scope of CSS is to be more [specific with your selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```
my-component div {
    /* some styles */
}
```

This will limit the styles applied to `div` to only those `<div>` tags found within the `<my-component>` element.

```
<my-component>
    <div>will get styled</div>
</my-component>

<div>won't get styled</div>
```

Comment: No, I mean selector specificity. I'll add a link explaining what that is, but it basically means including more of the hierarchy in your selector so it can differentiate one div from another.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a bundler like Webpack you also have options for namespacing. For example, [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) will allow you to pair a namespace with a module.  You'll import your CSS *into* your JS modules and have a specific, prefixed namespace that can be applied to every html classname attribute eg. `<a class="MyCoolNamespace__a" />`.

Otherwise, your best bet is specificity.  The more specific the selector, the higher the precedence. eg. `body > div > a.awesome` vs. `a.awesome`.

Finally remember that you can inline your styles.  An element style attribute `<a style="color:blue" />` should be the most specific and have no effect on other DOM elements.  Apparently, it has the [same specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) as an inline `<style />` tag declaration, but it will override the later.

It sounds like you may want to write or inject specific inline style blocks right before the html you are interested in styling.  If you can inject style blocks, you can also reset any styles that you may have defined to limit or *restrict* the use of some selectors. eg `div.awesome { margin:0; }`, etc.